# Trying to get my login code to work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I am following a tutorial on php/mysql/PDO called: PHP OOP Login/Register System.

I think the vid was created too long ago and things changed in the php code and now I am not getting the login success note.

login.php

```
    <?php
require_once '../core/config/conf.php';

if(Input::exists()) { 
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'gebruikersnaam' => array('required' => true),
            'wachtwoord' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validate->passed()) {
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('gebruikersnaam'), Input::get('wachtwoord'));

            if($login) {
                 echo (isset($user) && ($user->isLoggedIn())) ? 'Ingelogd!' : 'Inloggen ging fout.';            
        } else {
            foreach ($validate->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br />';
            }
        }

    }
}
}

?>

 <form action="" method="post">
     <div class="field">
         <label for="gebruikersnaam">Gebruikersnaam</label>
         <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" id="gebruikersnaam" autocomplete="on">
     </div>

     <div class="field">
         <label for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord</label>
         <input type="password" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" autocomplete="off">
     </div>

     <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
     <input type="submit" value="Inloggen">
 </form>
```

User.class.php

```
<?php

class User {

    private $_db,
                  $_data,
                  $_sessionName,
                  $_isLoggedIn = null;


    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance() ;
        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);
                if($user) {
                    ($this->find($user)) ? $this->_isLoggedIn = true : $this->_isLoggedIn = false;
                } else {
                    echo 'Class fout';
                }                    
            }
        } else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('Ooops... daar ging iets fout.');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));         

            if(($data) && ($data->count())) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }            
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($user = null, $pass = null) {
        if(isset($user) && ($this->find($user))) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($pass, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->u_id);
                return true;
            }
        }             
        return false;
    }

    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

This method isLoggedIn(); doesnt return true, even though I checked the login(); and find(); method and they appear to be working as planned but somehow it doesnt tell me that I am logged in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the _isloggedin variable

```
public function login($user = null, $pass = null) {
        if(isset($user) && ($this->find($user))) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($pass, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->u_id);
  // set it here
 $ this->_isloggedin = true;
                return true;
            }
        }             
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the edit scr I didn't know how to do it from my phone through the app, was just getting on my pc to do it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks so complicated. You can make a much simpler login script which won't leave your brain completely screwed. A quick type up of one here (won't be fully secured, check a good php security tutorial!) Best to start small, understand that, then get bigger.

```
<form action='au.php' method='POST'>
Username: <input type='text' name='user' />
Password: <input type='password' name='pass' />
<input type='submit' value='login' />
</form>
```

au.php

```
<?php
include "mysqli.php";
global $db;  // OOP form of mysqli

$user = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user']));
$pass = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['pass']));
$epass = md5($pass); // hashing a password isn't the best idea these days. Look into encrypting passwords

if(!isset($user) || !isset($pass))
{
echo " didn't fill out form";
} else {

$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$epass'");
$nr = $q->num_rows; // count the number of users (should only be one if data is entered right)
$ar = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
if($nr != 1)
{
   // error
} else {
   session_start();
   session_regenerate_id();
   $_SESSION['userid'] = $ar['userid'];
   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
   header("location:loggedin.php"); 
}
}
?>
```

After this all you need to do is check whether the $_SESSION['loggedin'] variable equals 1 to see if the user is logged in, and if they are then you can reference anything relating to them from $_SESSION['userid'].

Comment: Ok I understand it can be smaller and I am checking the code. But in that case I should just switch out the isLoggedIn method with the default $_SESSION[];?

Comment: Because you started about sessions I checked out how my own session worked and when I used this:

`$sessie = Config::get('session/session_name');`

echo `((Session::exists($sessie))) ? 'Ingelogd!' : 'Fout!';`

It recognizes my session name which tells me I am logged in.

Comment: I don't fully understand your code tbh with you. Despite that, you can only switch out the isLoggedIn method with the default $_SESSION[]; if you actually set variables for it.

Comment: It's this video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_hNNAdyfQk&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc)

Comment: Following up on your second comment: in that case for you to check if a user is logged in then can you not check to see if the session_name exists?